# c#: Как передать значение переменной класса вместо ссылки

Tags: c#, классы, ссылки

Создаю, значит, `lbGridMarkX` класса `Label`

```cs
Label lbGridMarkY = new Label(), lbGridMarkX = new Label();

lbGridMarkX.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
lbGridMarkX.Text = "0";
lbGridMarkX.Size = lbGridMarkX.PreferredSize;
lbGridMarkX.Location = panel1.Location;
lbGridMarkX.Top += height;
lbGridMarkX.Left -= lbGridMarkX.Size.Width / 2;
Controls.Add(lbGridMarkX);
lbGridMarkX.BringToFront();
```

основательно настраиваю его, и хочу создавать ещё почти такие же Label'ы каждые x пикселей:

```cs
цикл {
    Label New = new Label();
    New = lbGridMarkX;
    New.Text = (x * (gridUnitsX / gridStep)).ToString();
    New.Left += x;
    Controls.Add(New);
}
```

но проблема в том, когда я делаю `New = lbGridMarkX;`, то вместо значений, новой Label присывивается ссылка. И вместо создания новой Label каждых x пикселей, этот цикл просто передвигает одну и ту же Label.
Как мне скопировать переменную `lbGridMarkX`, в переменную `New`? `new Label(lbGridMarkX);` здесь не работает. Не присваивать же каждое значение по отдельности?

Comment: присваивать каждое значение по отдельности

Comment: У класса Label дофигилион значений. А если мне их все надо скопировать, мне код в 1000 строк писать?

Comment: код в 1000 строк писать

Comment: То, что вы хотите, зовется "копированием объекта", а копировать контролы, в WinForms, это как не крути нужна будет рефлексия, то есть вы должны взять класс `Lable`, взять коллекцию его свойств и в цикле пройтись, копируя их значения в новый объект. Я думаю, вы уже догадываетесь, что это весьма серьезная задача, которая может сильно ударить по производительности. И тут встает вопрос: А вам точно нужно "копирование", а не "создание"? Зачем вам вообще старый `Lable`, если вы можете создать сразу новый? Делайте метод "генерации", да и используйте его.

Comment: "вы должны взять класс Lable, взять коллекцию его свойств и в цикле пройтись, копируя их значения в новый объект" – так а разве создание нового объекта – не то же самое (за исключением того, что каждому свойству нового объекта присваивается не значение старого, а дефолтное значение)?

Comment: @Титан Когда вы создаете новый объект, его параметры будут дефольными, то есть вам надо их по новой задавать. Задать их вы можете двумя способами: 1. сделать метод, который будет внутри себя хранить эти значения, создавать новый объект и возвращать его обратно (`Lable CreateLable(){ var result = new Lable(); result.Text = "Привет мир!"; ... return result; }` и вызов `var first = CreateLable(); var second = CreateLable();`). Метод может быть где угодно, суть того, что параметры статичны, это не меняет. 2. Вы можете скопировать уже готовый через [рефлексию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10267292).

Answer (score 2):

```
private Label AssignCommonLabelProperties(Label lbl) {
  lbl.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
  ...
  return lbl;
}

Label lbGridMarkY = AssignCommonLabelProperties(new Label()); 
Label lbGridMarkX = AssignCommonLabelProperties(new Label());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class LbGridMarkX : Label
{
    public static List<LbGridMarkX> LbGridMarkXList = new List<LbGridMarkX>();
    public static int Count => LbGridMarkXList.Count;
    //
    public LbGridMarkX(Control Parent, Point Location, float Value, ushort decimals)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        this.Text = Value.ToString("N" + decimals);
        this.Size = this.PreferredSize;
        this.Top = Location.Y;
        this.Left = Location.X - (this.Size.Width / 2);
        //
        LbGridMarkXList.Add(this);
        if (Parent != null) Parent.Controls.Add(this);
        this.BringToFront();
    }
    public static void Clear()
    {
        for (int i = LbGridMarkXList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (LbGridMarkXList[i]?.Parent?.Controls.Contains(LbGridMarkXList[i]) ?? false)
                LbGridMarkXList[i].Parent.Controls.Remove(LbGridMarkXList[i]);
            LbGridMarkXList.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
    public static void AddLbGridMarkXGrid(Control Parent, Point StartLocation, float gridUnitsX, float gridStep, ushort decimals)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= gridUnitsX / gridStep; i++)
        {
            float value = i * gridStep;
            Point newlocation = new Point(StartLocation.X + (int)value, StartLocation.Y);
            WriteLine(newlocation);
            new LbGridMarkX(Parent, newlocation, value, decimals);
        }
    }
}
```

Добавление через:

```
LbGridMarkX.AddLbGridMarkXGrid(panel1, new Point(100, 100), 400, 100, 0);
LbGridMarkX.AddLbGridMarkXGrid(form1, new Point(0, 100), 300, 30.5f, 1); //или так
```

Очистка через:

```
LbGridMarkX.Clear();
```